# html template conditional tags

Tags: php, html, tags, conditional-statements

I have made a template editor with CKEditor and I would like to add inside some conditionals tags. For example :

```
{if variable == "value"} ok {else} not ok {/if}
```

I have 2 regex that works fine :

```
#\{if\s(.+?)}(.+?)\{else}(.+?)\{\/if}#s
#\{if\s(.+?)}(.+?)\{\/if}#s
```

It works well when I have only 1 level of condition but I would like to add several so for example doing something like this :

```
{if var == "value"} {if othervar == "value"} ok {/if} 2ndok {else} not ok {/if}
```

And then I have a problem the regex doesn't catch the condition in the good way.

Comment: Is building your own a good idea? Why not smarty

Comment: well it must be easy to use and I must not give the ability to have php actions to the final user

Comment: That's what it looks like you are doing here

Comment: for the "easy" part, users will have a training for using these tags. And for the "php" part the condition are validated before execution and they can access only a specific kind of value so everything is well secured and I don't allow to much to final user.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the regex? eg. ```preg_match```

Comment: sure I added the code in the question. it's a preg_replace_callback

Comment: Regexes are *not* a good tool for this. What you need to write is a parser.

Comment: well and do you have more info about this ?